# Puppeteer js element can be found only when developer tools is open

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to scrape the Instagram website using puppeteer and something very strange is happening. As I try clicking on the "followers" button of any given username with the following code:

```
await page.$eval('#react-root > section > main > div > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a > span', elem => elem.click());
```

I get prompted that there isn't any element with that selector.

[image]

Nevertheless, if I quickly activate the developer tools on the chrome page before the code is supposed to click on the button, the action works:
[image]

I would really like to know why this happens and how to get the button without having to open developer tools. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the element is only visible on the resized view? Are you sure it's there when you fully extend your screen?

Comment: You are indeed write. The element moves and becomes another div. Thanks!